# Removing/Purging linux-headers-3.16.0-30-generic, but apt-get wants to install linux-headers-3.16.0-50-generic

Tags: kernel

The command I am running is:

```
apt-get purge linux-headers-3.16.0-30 linux-headers-3.16.0-30-generic linux-image-3.16.0-30-generic linux-image-extra-3.16.0-30-generic linux-libc-dev --assume-yes
```

However, during the command,`apt-get` wants to install packages of version `3.16.0-50`. Here is the output:

```
The following extra packages will be installed:
  linux-generic-lts-utopic linux-headers-3.16.0-50
  linux-headers-3.16.0-50-generic linux-headers-generic-lts-utopic
  linux-image-3.16.0-50-generic linux-image-extra-3.16.0-50-generic
  linux-image-generic-lts-utopic

Suggested packages:
  fdutils linux-lts-utopic-tools

The following packages will be REMOVED:
  build-essential g++ g++-4.8 glusterfs-client glusterfs-common
  glusterfs-server libacl1-dev libattr1-dev libc6-dev libstdc++-4.8-dev
  linux-headers-3.16.0-30 linux-headers-3.16.0-30-generic
  linux-image-3.16.0-30-generic linux-image-extra-3.16.0-30-generic
  linux-libc-dev
```

Would anyone know why `apt-get` is installing the newer version of linux kernel `3.16.0-50` when I am trying to remove `3.16.0-30`? Is there any way to prevent this?

### System info

```
Distribution: Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS  
Current kernel: 3.19.0-30-generic
```

### apt-rdepends output

```
apt-rdepends -r --state-follow=Installed linux-headers-3.16.0-30 

linux-headers-3.16.0-30  
  Reverse Depends: linux-headers-3.16.0-30-generic (3.16.0-30.40~14.04.1)  
  Reverse Depends: linux-headers-3.16.0-30-lowlatency (3.16.0-30.40~14.04.1)  
linux-headers-3.16.0-30-generic  
  Reverse Depends: linux-headers-generic-lts-utopic (3.16.0.30.23)  
linux-headers-generic-lts-utopic  
  Reverse Depends: linux-generic-lts-utopic (= 3.16.0.50.41)  
  Reverse Depends: linux-headers-virtual-lts-utopic (= 3.16.0.50.41)  
  Reverse Depends: linux-hwe-generic-trusty (3.13.0.65.71)  
  Reverse Depends: linux-signed-generic-lts-utopic (= 3.16.0.50.41)  
linux-generic-lts-utopic
```

### List of all linux kernel packages

```
ii  linux-firmware                      1.127.15  
ii  linux-generic-lts-utopic            3.16.0.30.23  
ii  linux-generic-lts-vivid             3.19.0.30.17  
ii  linux-headers-3.16.0-30             3.16.0-30.40~14.04.1  
ii  linux-headers-3.16.0-30-generic     3.16.0-30.40~14.04.1  
ii  linux-headers-3.19.0-30             3.19.0-30.33~14.04.1  
ii  linux-headers-3.19.0-30-generic     3.19.0-30.33~14.04.1  
ii  linux-headers-generic-lts-utopic    3.16.0.30.23  
ii  linux-headers-generic-lts-vivid     3.19.0.30.17  
ii  linux-image-3.16.0-30-generic       3.16.0-30.40~14.04.1   
ii  linux-image-3.19.0-30-generic       3.19.0-30.33~14.04.1   
ii  linux-image-extra-3.16.0-30-generic 3.16.0-30.40~14.04.1   
ii  linux-image-extra-3.19.0-30-generic 3.19.0-30.33~14.04.1  
ii  linux-image-generic-lts-utopic      3.16.0.30.23  
ii  linux-image-generic-lts-vivid       3.19.0.30.17  
ii  linux-libc-dev:amd64                3.13.0-65.105
```

### apt-cache show linux-generic-lts-utopic

```
Depends: linux-image-generic-lts-utopic (= 3.16.0.30.23), linux-headers-generic-lts-utopic (= 3.16.0.30.23)
```

### apt-cache show linux-image-generic-lts-utopic

```
Depends: linux-image-3.16.0-30-generic, linux-image-extra-3.16.0-30-generic, linux-firmware
```

### apt-cache show linux-headers-generic-lts-utopic

```
Depends: linux-headers-3.16.0-30-generic
```

### apt-get in debug mode:

```
...
Broken linux-image-generic-lts-utopic:amd64 Depends on linux-image-3.16.0-50-generic  
Broken linux-headers-generic-lts-utopic:amd64 Depends on linux-headers-3.16.0-50-generic  
...
```

Comment: This is probably because you have the generic linux 3.6 packages installed. Please post the output of the following (in the question, not in a comment) `dpkg -l | grep linux-image` and also `dpkg -l | grep linux-headers`. By generic I mean something like `linux-image-amd64`. This needs to depend on something, so my guess is that it is pulling a different version of 3.16. Also post the output of `apt-cache policy`. And what is your distribution and version?

Comment: Distribution: Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS,   

Current kernel: 3.19.0-30-generic

Comment: Ok, also, please paste text rather than images. It's easier for a number of reasons, including page size, ability to cut and paste, and ability to search. Also put other information like distribution into the question too. Also, please state what you are trying to do. Are you trying to remove all 3.16 packages from your system, leaving only 3.19 packages? If so, the simplest thing would be to remove all linux related packages with version 3.16 from your system. Make sure you are running 3.19 first, of course.

Comment: yes, I want to only keep 3.19 packages and remove all of 3.16 packages. I can remove of 3.16 packages if I try to remove 3.16.0-30, then 3.16.0-50 with the command in the original question. However, I want to understand the behavior of why linux wants to install 3.16.0-50 when I'm trying to remove 3.16.0-30.

Comment: Please rerun your `apt-get` command with the addition of `-o Debug::pkgProblemResolver=true`, paste into your question, and please don't use an image. And get rid of the images you have, please. Thanks.

Comment: Also include the output of `apt-cache show linux-generic-lts-utopic` in the question, but the `Depends:` line only.

Comment: I added the output to the question as well as an answer to the question. Thanks for your help!

Comment: If you have an answer, post it as an answer (you can answer your own question), not as part of the question. Also, please post the complete output of `apt-get purge` in debug mode. The two lines you posted are presumably not all of it. Also, can you post the output for `apt-cache show linux-image-generic-lts-utopic` and `apt-cache show linux-headers-generic-lts-utopic`? Again, just the `Depends` line.

Answer (score 1):

The linux-generic-lts-utopic depends on 3.16.0-30. If 3.16.0-30 is removed, apt-get will install 3.16.0-50 as a dependency to replace 3.16.0-30.
Thus, removing linux-generic-lts-utopic first will remove any dependency and will allow a clean purging of all 3.16.